# Code review for a collection manipulation tool in Javascript

Tags: javascript, optimization, library

As I was working with .NET, I started wondering how I would implement the LINQ methods syntax in Javascript. So here is my first try; is there a more elegant, or more performant, way to write this code?

```
// usage : the functions take a predicate function as input and modify the array accordingly 
var collection;
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var Collections = function(array) {
        this.array = array;
    };

    Collections.prototype = {
        //The predicate should return a boolean value
        //Keeps all elements that match the given function
        where: function(predicate) {
            var newArray = [];
            this.each(function(index, item) {
                if (predicate(item)) {
                    newArray.push(item);
                }
            });
            this.array = newArray;
            return this;
        },
        //The predicate should return a boolean value
        //Returns true if one element or more matches the predicate
        any: function(predicate) {
            var newArray = [];
            this.each(function(index, item) {
                if (predicate(item)) {
                    newArray.push(item);
                }
            });
            return newArray.length > 0;
        },
        //The predicate should return an object
        //Replaces all elements by the object generated by the predicate
        select: function(predicate) {
            var newArray = [];
            this.each(function(index, item) {
                newArray.push(predicate(item));
            });
            this.array = newArray;
            return this;
        },
        //Returns the current (modified) array
        getArray: function() {
            return this.array;
        }
    };

    collection = function(array) {
        return new Collections(array);
    };
} ());
```

And here is an exemple of use:

```
var myArray = [{name: 'chicken', size: 1}, {name: 'cat', size: 2}, 
{name: 'dog', size: 3}, {name: 'horse', size: 4}, {name: 'skunk', size: 2}];
var newArray = collection(myArray)
    .where(function(animal){
        return animal.size == 2
    })
    .select(function(animal){
        return {
            animalName: animal.name,
            category: 'mammal',
            size: 'small'
        }
    })
    .getArray()
// new array : [{animalName: 'cat', category: 'mammal', size: 'small}, {animalName: 'skunk', 
// category: 'mammal', size: 'small'}]
```

Comment: So you're rewriting [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)?

Comment: Not the whole library obviously. I just wanted to work on something small to experiment with the code and try to improve my code style.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with that.  Just keeping you from rewriting an existing library from scratch.  :)

Comment: Why is Collections in plural? It is more common to find constructor names in singular (Array, String, Object).

Comment: @Eric: Good point, I didn't think about that. Neil: thank you then !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify the use of your global variable "collection" as a namespace for your library, you should assign it directly to a value returned by your Immediately Invoked Function Expression:

```
var collection = (function(){
  ...

  function collection(array) {
    return new Collections(array);
  }

  return collection;
}());
```

Comment: Alright, it does seem clearer that way.